# C function to determine if IP address is multicast address

Tags: c, linux, sockets

If user enters some IP address like "239.4.4.4", how can I determine this IP address is multicast using any function if available in linux C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**********************************************************************************************************************
 * Checks if specified IP is multicast IP. Multicast IP ranges from 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255.
 *
 * Returns 0 if specified IP is not multicast IP, else non-zero.
 *
 * Parameters:
 *      ip                          IP to check for multicast IP, stored in network byte-order.
 *********************************************************************************************************************/
int net_ip__is_multicast_ip(in_addr_t ip){
    char *ip_str = (char *) &ip;

    int i = ip_str[0] & 0xFF;

    // we will check only first byte of IP
    // and if it from 224 to 239, then it can
    // represent multicast IP.
    if(i >=  224 && i <= 239){
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can replace the conditional with `return (ip_str[0] & 0xF0) == 0xE0;`.
Since ipaddr_t is uint32_t the whole body could be just `return (ip & 0xF0000000) == 0xE0000000;` -- which would be suiteable for a macro too.

Comment: Aren't IP addresses stored as big-endian, per the standard? Therefore, won't `(ip & 0xF0000000)` be testing the wrong byte on a little-endian system?

Comment: yeah, thats why I took pointer to char*, and ip_str[0] is MSByte in big-endian form.

Comment: No, because the mask will be stored the same. 1 & 1 will equal 1 regardless of the endian.

Answer (score 6):

IPv4 multicast addresses are defined by the most significant bits `1110`, so:

1. if the IP address is stored as 32bit **unsigned** variable, apply a `>> 28` to the variable, then check if the result is `14` (`1110`), like `isMulti = ((address >> 28) == 14);`.
2. if the IP address is stored as a tuple of 4 unsigned chars, then check if the first (MSB) is between 224 and 239, included.

Answer (score 5):

```
bool isMulticastAddress(in_addr_t s_addr)
{
    //in_addr_t stored in network order
    uint32_t address = ntohl(s_addr);

    return (address & 0xF0000000) == 0xE0000000;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain your answer a bit more.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11679944)

Comment: A valid multicast IPv4 address is between 224.0.0.0 and 239.255.255.255.  Checking the leading byte to make sure it is between 224 and 239, inclusive, is the obvious answer.  But recognizing that 224 = 0xE0 and 239 = 0xEF, checking the first nibble against 0xE is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Multicast addresses ranges from 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address

So it should be enough for you to check the whether the address falls within range.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need a function to determine whether an address is a multicast one, just look at its range: if the first byte is [between 224 and 239](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address) (included), it's a multicast address, within the class D.

> IPv4 multicast addresses are defined by the leading address bits of 1110, originating from the classful network design of the early Internet when this group of addresses was designated as Class D. The Classless Inter-Domain Routing (CIDR) prefix of this group is 224.0.0.0/4. The group includes the addresses from 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255

Of course IPv6 has its own scheme, but there multicast addresses start with `ff00::`. Anyway, refer to the wikipedia article for that.

Oh, and finally, if you want us to give you ways of checking that in C, you need to give more details on what is the representation of your IP address. Is it a 4 bytes struct? Is it a four bytes integer? Is it an array of characters?

Comment: The RFC are referenced from wikipedia, and the article is based upon those. I'm not refering to wikipedia when I have any doubt on the article, but here the information I'm referring to in the article are exact, so I see no reasons not to quote them.

Answer (score 1):

With Linux, you can use the `IN_MULTICAST()` macro [defined](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/in.h#L268) in `in.h`. For example,

```
bool a = IN_MULTICAST(ntohl(inet_addr("239.4.4.4")));
```