# How to verify that an address is unicast?

Tags: c, network-programming, ip, multicast, unicast

Given an IPv4 address, I can verify whether the address is multicast in C by using the `IN_MULTICAST` macro from `netinet/in.h` header file. Similarly, for IPv6 I can use the `IN6_IS_ADDR_MULTICAST` macro from `netinet/in6.h`.

Is there any way to verify that a particular address is *unicast*? This would probably entail discarding other addressing methods like anycast and broadcast.

Ideally, but not necessarily, the solution to this would be in the C language.

Comment: Check this answer. Then use the macro defined in in.h to achieve what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48238426/2540947

Comment: @LêQuangDuy He knows that. Read the question.

Comment: @user207421 Please enlighten me, maybe my knowledge/English is not enough, so what does he want to achieve, exactly? a macro, a method to verify an address is unicast or something else?